# How to POST multiple related entities with Entity Framework + OData?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, odata

What is the proper way to POST multiple related entities and check required properties?

I have two entities `Product` and `Package`. A `Product` can have many `Packages`. A `Package` cannot exist without a related `Product`.

When I POST a new `Product` with a collection of multiple `Packages`, the `ModelState` says the model is invalid because the `Packages` do not have their required `productId` foreign key set. This causes my API to return a `BAD REQUEST` status.

It's my understanding that [Entity Framework supports this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data). I would expect the `ModelState` to detect that the Package `productId` FK will be set automatically and thus wouldn't be invalid.

If I remove the block of code that checks the `ModelState` validity Entity Framework behaves as expected and the `Product` and `Packages` are created.

```
POST /api/v1/Products
BODY
{
   "name": "Coca-Cola",
   "packages": [
        {
            "count": 6,
            "quantity": 12,
            "quantityUnit": "oz"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my controller function:

```
[HttpPost]
[ODataRoute("")]
[EnableQuery]
public virtual async Task<IActionResult> PostEntity([FromBody] Product entityToCreate)
{
    //Removing this block will cause the request to succeed
    // but will also allow invalid requests to get to the database
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    _context.Packages.Add(entityToCreate);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Created("DefaultApi", entityToCreate);
}
```

And here are my models:

```
public class Product: ModelBase
{
    [Required]
    public string name { get; set; }

    public List<Package> packages { get; set; }
}

public class Package: ModelBase
{
    //some required props...

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("product")]
    public Guid? productId { get; set; }
    public Product product { get; set; }
}
```

Some things I've investigated:

1. Dropping the `[Required]` attribute on `packageId` and manually editing the db migration to include the constraint. This causes an error to be thrown later in the stack by the database. I'd rather fail before getting to the database
2. Writing my own validation attributes. This seems unnecessary given that the EF documentation claims to support this
3. Possibly using OData Batch Requests

Comment: To resolve it, have the ProductId required in both db and the model and then assign the product id in your POST. BTW,  your Product model should have ProductID.

Comment: My models all extend the `ModelBase` class that contains the [Key] property. The key is database generated and I don't want to have to manually implement this logic for every single type. If the tree of data I'm posting is large (and in my use cases it most certainly is) this becomes a huge task - one that the documentation claims to already support!

Comment: Your problem is that you are using the same objects (`Product`, `Package`) for different data representations. You should use DTO as advised in the answer below. Data annotations (RequiredAttribute) are interpreted by both - model validator and EF. Fluent API is a better choice to describe model with richer options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically create a very specific "model" class (not an entity) to represent the payload of an HTTP Post (Put, Patch, etc.). In this case you'd want a set of models. Then I have validation rules specific this set of models. Some call these models, DTOs, ViewModels, etc. The important thing is that they are not EF entities.

After verifying their validity, you will have to map these models into the appropriate entities so they can be persisted with EF. This mapping is the unfortunate tax of decoupling your entities from your exposed models. You can do this manually or use a library like [automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).

There are many advantages to this strategy:

- You can support several variations of manipulating your persisted Product/Package data without having to accommodate each of the variations with one set of entities. This means you can sensibly create and expose different sets of properties (models) with different validation rules for the same persisted data types (entities).
- You protect yourself from [overposting](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETOverpostingMassAssignmentModelBindingSecurity.aspx). You don't want the user to be able to set the state of all properties without restriction.
- Your exposed endpoints (controller actions) have parameters that are decoupled from your entities. This means that you can freely change the entities without necessarily having to change the exposed models that represent them and vice versa. You could hypothetically abandon EF altogether and move to some neat NoSQL persistence solution without having to change your expose APIs.

Comment: I ended up changing my implementation to use this strategy. I was hoping to have one generic odata controller to manage my basic CRUD operations. Instead, I disabled POST from my abstract odata controller and now require my specific entity controllers to implement their own methods to create data. I ended up using automapper, which was pretty easy to set up with the dependency injector.

Comment: That's great. Glad to hear you've settled on a nice solution.